# Cygwin chmod 777 command made other users 'access denied' in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, file-permissions, chmod

I am administrator of a Windows 7 system, created some spreadsheets (.CVS files) and changed the permission of those files by CHMOD 777 command (from CYGWIN console), so that other users can get full access to read and write. But, after the permission changed to (chmod 777), other users (non administrators) can't get access to those files, it errors 'access denied'.

In the recent past, I did similar file permission change in Windows XP without any problem, why it is happening in Windows 7 ? How can I resolve it ?

Please help !

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic here.  What are you using Cygwin for?

Comment: @ Harry Johnston: Nice question, even though this is not 'on-topic'. Cygwin is used here for some historical reason, there were some bash scripts developed before which writes data to .CSV files. Regardless of Cygwin or DOS, I understand that Windows 7 introduced stringent security to the file system.

Comment: There was no change to the file system in Windows 7, the security improvements were in other areas.  Presumably the actual permissions on the files are only allowing access to administrators (and the owner?) but in Windows XP all of your accounts probably had administrator access.  I don't know why Cygwin would be setting the "wrong" permissions, perhaps you're using an out-of-date version?

Comment: On the *Windows* command line, you can check the permissions of an affected file with the `icacls` command, e.g., `icacls myfile.txt`.  Please copy and paste the output of that command into your question.